# Add small logo top left on Quarto presentation title slide using reveal.js

Tags: html, reveal.js, quarto

How can I add a small logo top left of my Quarto presentation title slide using reveal.js?

Info about Quarto/reveal.js presentations: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add a logo only in Title slide in top-left corner, an easy way to do this is using the `title-slide-attributes` to specify background image and then scale the img to small and then move the img in top-left corner.

#### Reprex

---

**presentation.qmd**

```
---
title: "Logo in top-left corner"
format: revealjs
title-slide-attributes: 
  data-background-image: quarto.png
  data-background-size: 15%
  data-background-position: 2% 2%
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished
presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations see
<https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.

## Bullets

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code
```

**quarto.png**

[image: quarto.logo]

---

**rendered output**

[image: logo in top left corner of Title Slide]

---